# The type or namespace name 'ServiceController' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to check a service in C#, I have added the `System.ServiceProcess.dll`

Although I get the error:

> Error  2   The type or namespace name 'ServiceController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\App\Form1.cs 247 13  App

My code is as follows:

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Spooler");

    if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The service is running.");
    }
}
```

Do I perhaps need a "using" statement?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the System.ServiceProcess.dll

[image]

After that, you will be able to see it in Visual Studio, as one of the `using` statements you can add to your project:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Pro Tip**: When you are trying to use a class from the .NET Framework and you get a message like:

> The type or namespace name '...' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Lookup the type in the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library) and look under the Inheritance Hierarchy section to find the Namespace and Assembly you need.

**Inheritance Hierarchy**

```
System.Object   
  System.MarshalByRefObject  
    System.ComponentModel.Component  
      System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController
```

**Namespace:**  *System.ServiceProcess*
**Assembly:**  System.ServiceProcess (in *System.ServiceProcess.dll*)

Then ensure that you have [a reference to the assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and a [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) for the namespace (assuming you don't want to fully qualify the name).

Comment: Thanks, that will be handy for the future

Answer (score 3):

Yes, at the top.

`using System.ServiceProcess;`

Answer (score 1):

For me (Visual Studio 2012) it was not a default addition when typing in "using"
I had to add a reference and search through the assemblies for System.ServiceProcess. (I believe it is located in the .NET tab in older versions of Studio).
Hope this helps any future viewers!

Comment: This is the exact same answer as the Accepted Answer, except without a supporting graphic.