# Visual Studio 2010 reference errors I can't figure out

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

this morning I started my visual studio 2010. and I clicked start then these errors came up. and I have no idea where it come from and why it gives these errors. because the day before I had no problems starting it and everything worked.

it is an MVC 3 Razor project. on visual studio 2010

[image: Error list visual studio]

sorry for bad english.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and then build the project (or used the rebuild option)?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8893408/541432

Comment: @BerndLinde yes I clean build the project serveral times. I restart visual studio. I restarted my pc still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you update your computer with Windows Update? Microsoft did release critical MVC fix a day ago, with this update they also change few interfaces so SOME projects wont build any more without changing updating references.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx

I belive you are experiencing the same problems, please refer the link above

Comment: thanks this solved the errors. now i get errors in my global.asax.cs GlobalFilterCollection could not be found.