# The Type or namespace 'ServiceController' could not be found

Tags: c#, service

I have created a window service and i am using it in my classes. I just want to check if

service is running or not .  For that i have just added reference to

**System.ServiceProcess.dll** in my project and trying this below code.

```
  System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(SERVICENAME);
```

But it is giving error : **The Type or namespace 'ServiceController'  could not be found**

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name 'ServiceController' could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238295/the-type-or-namespace-name-servicecontroller-could-not-be-found)

Comment: I have seen that thread, but it doesn't solve  this issue.

Comment: did u added 'using System.ServiceProcess;' to your class?

Comment: if you will see my question , that i have added reference that dll.

Comment: And still  i am not getting its reference why ?

Comment: `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` is not same as  `using System.ServiceProcess;`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, solved it with changing:

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(SERVICENAME);
```

to this:

```
var sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(SERVICENAME);
```

Comment: i have included System.ServiceProcess in references..  but I get get error when I add.. . using Sysetm.ServiceProcess at TOP.  what can be the problem.

Comment: then use the full version of CodeCaster in the next answer. If u really added the correct reference, u have to use `using System.ServiceProcess`

Answer (score 0):

Just read the error and look at the exact location of the red line in your IDE.

You have

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc = 
    new ServiceController(SERVICENAME);
```

The second time you don't use the namespace, and apparently you are missing a `using` statement.

You can fix this in two ways:

Use the full namespace:

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc = 
    new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(SERVICENAME);
```

Or add a `using` statement at the beginning of your file:

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

// ...

ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(SERVICENAME);
```